# How to integrate Kinesis Video Stream with Kinesis Video Rekognition for dectecting persons

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-rekognition

Using Raspberry pi got the live video streaming using Kinesis Video Streaming Parser library and want to process stream to Kinesis Video Rekognition for detecting persons.

Set the required details of ARN, got the video stream an set to Frame Viewer. Then trying to integrate Kinesis Video Stream with Rekognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to these examples:

https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library#kinesisvideo---rekognition-examples

KinesisVideoRekognitionIntegrationExample decodes H264 frames and renders them with bounding boxes on the previewer locally using JFrame.

KinesisVideoRekognitionLambdaExample decodes H264 frames, overlaps bounding boxes, encodes to H264 frames again and ingests them into a new Kinesis Video streams.